# Flutter: Rounded Container and ClipRRect corners don't line up

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Container` with a `BoxDecoration` that gives it rounded corners and a border. For its child, I have a `ClipRRect` with the same border radius as the `Container`. Even though both of these have the same border radius, the corners don't line up (there's a tiny transparent gap).

[image: The corners don't line up]

What causes this, and how should I go about fixing it?

Comment: Can you show screen shot

Comment: @AadityasivaSabarinathan It's done, should've done that from the start.

Comment: do not use `ClipRRect` then, use `ShapeDecoration` and `Container.clipBehavior` instead

Comment: You have to use the same size... seems that the height and width are not the same at the child and the parent